# Can't click div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website to view your stats from my Minecraft Pocket Edition server, and I am having a problem.

I have one div with the id "tabs-minigames" and in this div there are 4 boxes with icons, which are these "tabs", and this div is currently not shown (in css display none)
Now, I have a image at the top of the website that you should be able to click to show the div "tabs-minigames", and the tabs show, but don't disappear after clicking a second time. I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

I am using this function in jQuery to show and hide the minigames tab:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var status = false;
        $('#sliderimg').on('click', function(){
            if(!status){
                $("#tabs-minigames").show();
                status = true;
            }else{
                $("#tabs-minigames").hide();
                status = false;
            }
        });
    });
```

I don't see anything wrong with the function, and here is the HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            View your stats - Legion PE 
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"></link>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var status = false;
        $('#sliderimg').on('click', function(){
            if(!status){
                $("#tabs-minigames").show();
                status = true;
            }else{
                $("#tabs-minigames").hide();
                status = false;
            }
        });
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <div class="tabs-back">
                <div id="tabs-middle">
                        <img id="sliderimg" src="graphics/slider.png" height="100" width="100" style="position: fixed;padding-left:20px;padding-top: 10px;" style="outline:none;cursor: pointer;"></img>
                    <div style="padding-left:150px;padding-top:25px;">
                        <div id="tab-light-box">
                                Legion PE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-minigames" style="display: none;outline: none;">
            <div class="tabs-minigame">
                <img src="icons/kitpvp_fullsize.png" width="120" height="110" style="padding-left:15px;padding-top:20px;"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-minigame">
                <img src="icons/spleef_fullsize.png" width="120" height="120" style="padding-left:15px;padding-top:15px;"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-minigame">
                <img src="icons/bowandarrow_fullsize.png" width="120" height="120" style="padding-left:15px;padding-top:15px;"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-minigame">
                <img src="icons/diamond_fullsize.png" width="120" height="120" style="padding-left:15px;padding-top:15px;"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <center>
        <div id="center">
        </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see the website live here: http://legionpvp.eu/pe/login/stats.html

Thanks!

Comment: you should be very specific on which div is clicked. otherwise, its going to bubble.

Comment: oh I see xD sorry
still doesn't work though :/

Comment: Use Chrome developer tools to se if something is covering it. Also use `.on` instead of live/delegate

Comment: or use: $('#slider').on('click', function(){});

Comment: FYI, your document ready handler is useless here

Comment: alright, I now put the status variable in the document ready handler and the tabs now show, but don't hide after clicking a second time

Comment: @Lambo You get z-index issue regarding clicking second time, just inspect the button once tabs open, you'll see what i mean. Regarding issue of `status`, this explains it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.status  But anyway instead of checking for a variable, you should use `slideToggle()` or `toggle()` etc...

Comment: I fixed most of it, but regarding these z-index issues, how do I fix them?

Comment: Use e.g: `#tabs {z-index: 1;}` as CSS rule

Comment: I removed position:fixed; from the mini-games tab, but now the background does a weird zoom effect (have a look http://legionpvp.eu/pe/login/stats.html)

Answer (score 2):

you don't have any element with id="div", and that's what you're binding your click to... There's an image with another id, did you mean to use

```
.delegate("#sliderimg", "click", function(){

}
```

Also as others have pointed out it's best to use jquery.on(), or in your case you can even just use `$('#sliderimg').click()` unless you plan to add / remove the element with that id to the page.

Comment: thanks, I just tried it though but it still does nothing

Answer (score 2):

you can try this with no need for anything to be true or false

```
$('#sliderimg').on('click',function(){
  $('#tabs-minigames').slideToggle();  // you can use fadeToggle() as well
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable in the $(document).ready function

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var status = false;
        $("#sliderimg").on("click", function () {
            if (status === false) {
                $("#tabs-minigames").show();
                status = true;
            } else {
                $("#tabs-minigames").hide();
                status = false;
            }
        });
    });
```